# Constructing curves with large tangent space in complex variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a (singular) complex analytic/algebraic variety. Then for every $p\in M$ there exists a (possibly reducible) curve $C \subset U\subseteq M$ containing $p$ such that $T_pC=T_pM$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $p\in M$. An inductive proof of this statement can be found in the paper "Holomorphic and differentiable tangent spaces to complex analytic varieties" by J. Becker (1977) (here is the ProjectEuclid [link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-12/issue-3/Holomorphic-and-differentiable-tangent-spaces-to-a-complex-analytic-variety/10.4310/jdg/1214434091.full)).

The author proves the result by showing that one can always find a codimension $1$ variety with the same tangent space and then by induction one can also find a curve. In the paper the authors choose countably many codimension $1$ varieties $p\in X_i$ such that $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} X_i$ is dense in $U$ and concludes that a finite union of these varieties already have the same tangent space. The proof given relies on the ideals defining the $X_i$'s to be height $1$ prime ideals.

Intuitively I thought the following statement must then be easily provable:

Suppose $M$ is a complex variety and $p\in M$. Let $C_i\subset U\subseteq M$ be countably many complex curves such that $p\in C_i$ and $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}C_i$ is dense in $U$. Then the union of finitely many of the $C_i$'s have the same tangent space at $p$ as $M$.

I tried to play around with this, but I was not able to come up with a proof. Has anyone seen this or a similar result discussed somewhere? Or any ideas how to tackle the problem? Of course one can try to choose hypersurfaces $X_i$ containing $C_i$. Then finitely many of the $X:= \bigcup_{i=1}^m X_i$'s span the tangent space of $M$ at $p$. But in general only finitely many of the $C_i$'s will be entirely contained in $X$. So this won't easily work iteratively.